# Laravel - Get value instances via facades

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` abstract In method

```
protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
    {
        if (is_object($name)) {
            return $name;
        }

        if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name])) {
            return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
        }

        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
    }
```

`static::$app` is an instance of Application. And `static::$app[$name]` that like access value of `array`, and i don't understand that, What technique here?

ex: `static::$app['router']` it return instance of `Router`. Seem that get values of `protected $instances` in `Illuminate\Container\Container`

I think it like example ? but got `FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Foo as array`

```
class Foo
{
    public $bar = 'barValue';
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo['bar'];
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. please elaborate. What do you need to do?

Comment: @GabMic please take a look, i just update my question

Comment: You don't need to poke in that method. what exactly to you need? what value do you need?

Comment: @GabMic i try to understand how it working, and i don't know `static::$app[$name]` call what `method` or `property` of instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the API of [Illuminate\Container\Container](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Container/Container.html), you will notice that it implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and consequently the following methods.

1. offsetExists()
2. offsetGet()
3. offsetSet()
4. offsetUnset()

ArrayAccess lets you access objects as arrays. Here's a very simplistic example of a Container.

```
<?php

class Container implements ArrayAccess {

    private $items = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = [
            'one'   => 1,
            'two'   => 2,
            'three' => 3,
        ];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->items[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->items[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->items[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->items[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->items[$offset]) ? $this->items[$offset] : null;
    }
}

$container = new Container();

echo $container['one']; // outputs 1

$container['four'] = 4; // adds 4 to $items. 

echo $container['four']; // outputs 4
```

As you can see, you can access the Container object as an array since it implements `ArrayAccess`.

It also doesn't matter if the `items` property is not publicly accessible. In any case, the implementation of ArrayAccess means that it will allow us to retrieve those values as if they were in an array.